# how to setup sharepoint to work with fqdn vice server name

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am a beginner sharepoint person trying to stand up a on-premise sharepoint 2013 server.

The server works great when going to it like this http://server/  but if I were to use DNS-FQDN (ie. http://server.domain.com/)  it fails.  The DNS server does route to the correct station, so I'm thinking it's a setting in sharepoint.  How do I troubleshoot?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a SharePoint behaviour but the DNS. When you navigate to http://server/ you use the machine name and not DNS, with FQDN you use the DNS. Try to execute this command into command prompt: **ping server.domain.com** and see what append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to add an alternate access mapping in Central Administration and an IIS binding for your web application to use the FQDN.

See
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: That's what it was. Thanks much